# vncsession vs real-desktop window opening

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, vnc, icewm

As the title already spoils, I have a Ubuntu machine on which I have installed a vncserver to use it remotely. The machine is always powered up, and when I am physically there I use the "real" screen(s) which are connected to it, so likely there is always a gnome-session running. I know this is a "bad setup", but unluckily I cannot really change it...

The problem is that when I start some applications in my vncsession, which uses on IceWM, these windows spawn on the gnome-session, aka on the physical screen of the machine. These applications are usually something like Firefox or Gedit.

This is my xstartup file :

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
icewm-session &
```

Do you have any hints on why this could be happening?

I tried looking in the vncsession-logfile but it is blank, no hints about the windows not being able to spawn on the vncsession, just them appearing on the gnome-session.